# Why can't i add postgresql pg in yarn add?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

So i'm trying to add postgresql pg in yarn add, but it says that it's not found.

Code:

```
yarn add "@mikro-orm/postgresql pg"
yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@mikro-orm%2fpostgresql%20pg: Not found".
```

Comment: The space + "pg" is breaking it, just remove those

Comment: Why are you quoting the package names like that? How are you actually running this?

Comment: i was just following tutorial on youtube, and dude wrote yarn add "@mikro-orm/postgresql pg" in terminal and it worked, but i can't get it worked

Answer (score 1):

In order to add `@mikro-orm`'s repo `postgresql` you have to remove `pg`

`yarn add @mikro-orm/postgresql`

Comment: But then `pg` isn't also installed, which may not be the behaviour the OP wants.

Comment: The OP means `yarn add "@mikro-orm/postgresql" pg` maybe, but then you can remove quotes : `yarn add @mikro-orm/postgresql pg`

Comment: Actually, i followed the tutorial on youtube, before that i couldn't do "yarn add <package>, so i added quotations, but now i can't install postgresql pg like in the tutorial